# Python3 check if list contains only tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, typechecking

I have tried the following:

```
vrs = [('first text', 1),
       ('second text', 2),
       ('third text', 3),
       ('fourth text', 4),
       ('fifth text', 5),
       ('sixth text', 6),
       ('seventh text', 7),
       ('eighth text', 8),
       ('ninth text', 9),
       ('tenth text', 10),
       ('eleventh text', 11),
       ('twelfth text', 12)
      ]

if all(vr is tuple for vr in vrs):
    print('All are tuples')
else:
    print('Error')

if set(vrs) == {tuple}:
    print('All are tuples')
else:
    print('Error')
```

The output is `Error` for both.

Is there any way to check for this (i.e. check if every element in a list is a tuple)  without a loop?

Comment: Have you tried `isinstance`?

Comment: In what configuration? If you replace the `is`  or the `==` above you get an error.

Comment: @user3865473 `isinstance` is a function, not an operator

Comment: Ok... do as is shown below. :) Thanks everyone.

Comment: A built in function that I didn't even know about. I made it a point to read [python built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) because I am new to Python (from a non scripting language), but I haven't really gotten around to it in the past few days.

Comment: @user3865473 if you're new to Python, you should really think about whether you need to check this at all - would e.g. a list of lists be a problem for your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#isinstance):

`isinstance(object, classinfo)`

*Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.*

```
vrs = [('first text', 1),
   ('second text', 2),
   ('third text', 3),
   ('fourth text', 4),
   ('fifth text', 5),
   ('sixth text', 6),
   ('seventh text', 7),
   ('eighth text', 8),
   ('ninth text', 9),
   ('tenth text', 10),
   ('eleventh text', 11),
   ('twelfth text', 12)
  ]    
all(isinstance(x,tuple) for x in vrs)
True
vrs = [('first text', 1),
   ('second text', 2),
   ('third text', 3),
   ('fourth text', 4),
   ('fifth text', 5),
   ('sixth text', 6),
   ('seventh text', 7),
   ('eighth text', 8),
   ('ninth text', 9),
   ('tenth text', 10),
   ('eleventh text', 11),
   'twelfth text'
  ]
  all(isinstance(x,tuple) for x in vrs)
  False
```

Comment: This does answer the question but cannot address why a Python programmer would ever do this. I simply cannot imagine what ensuring the elements of a list are tuples would buy you. @Dylan I can hand you `[(1, 2) (3,) ('four', 'five', 6), (7, 8, 9, 10)]` all of which will pass the predicate but will almost certainly cause a fault somewhere down the line. You should understand why [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is the norm in Python; largely because it doesn't pretend to solve problems that it can't.

Answer (score 2):

`vr is tuple` doesn't check whether the object bound to the name `vr` is of type `tuple`, it checks whether *the names are bound to the same object* (i.e. evaluates whether `id(vr) == id(tuple)`). Inevitably, they aren't; `tuple` is a `type` instance, not a `tuple` instance!

Instead, you should use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if all(isinstance(vr, tuple) for vr in vrs):
```

This supports inheritance (unlike e.g. `if all(type(vr) == tuple ...)`), so this would also allow e.g. a `namedtuple` in the input.

However, in Python it is not always necessary to check the type of specific objects (it uses strong, dynamic typing, also known as ["duck typing"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#term-duck-typing)). Although it is not clear why you want to ensure they are all tuples, is it possible that, for example, all being [*sequence types*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) (e.g. `tuple`, `list`, `str`) would be acceptable?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a filter to remove all tuple elements, such as:

```
nontuples = filter(lambda vr : vr is not tuple, vrs)
```

And then check that the remaining iterable is empty.  It won't be a list if you're in Python 3.x, but you can make it a list with

```
nontuples = list(nontuples)
```

Comment: `is not tuple` doesn't check whether an object is an instance of tuple, though, it checks to see whether the object is actually the same object as the one currently named `tuple` (which is probably the built-in type.)